# cppcheck error doesn't match what I see

Tags: cppcheck

I run cppcheck and I get this message:
    "Member variable
    'i_refvec::data_' is not assigned a value in
    'i_refvec::operator='."

The code is from the template numerical toolkit (TNT).  I *think* I see these variables getting initialized, but I still get the complaint.

Help?

The pertinent function (starting at line 155) goes:

```
template <class T>
i_refvec<T> & i_refvec<T>::operator=(const i_refvec<T> &V)
{
  // Do nothing if we're pointing at ourselves
    if (this == &V)
        return *this;

    if (ref_count_ != NULL)
    {
        (*ref_count_) --;
        if ((*ref_count_) == 0)
            destroy();
    }

    data_ = V.data_;
    ref_count_ = V.ref_count_;

    if (V.ref_count_ != NULL)
        (*(V.ref_count_))++;

    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a Cppcheck developer.

It looks like a false positive to me also. I wonder if you can reduce it to a short example code which reproduces the problem.. and then report a ticket here: http://trac.cppcheck.net.

False positives are often caused by some tiny detail. Possibly somewhere else. Therefore it's hard to say why this might fail.

If you want to create an example code that reproduce the false positive, it's best to reduce your original code (removing includes, classes, methods, etc).

Comment: TNT and cppcheck don't seem to play well together, maybe because TNT is so heavy on the templates? (TNT is all headers, no cpp code).  It was also claiming that member objects weren't getting initialized.  I'll try to get some examples together for you.